# Two Domain Objects in One View

Tags: grails

Can two domain objects show on the same page, when the list method is called, for example?

http://APP_NAME/foo/list

---

```
def list = {
    if(!params.max) params.max = 10
    [ fooList: Foo.list( params ) ]
    [ barList: Bar.list( params ) ]  // Only the last one is returned.

}
```

---

On the view page, both tables would be displayed on the page.

```
 <g:each in="${fooList}" status="i" var="foo"> ... </g:each>
 <g:each in="${barList}" status="i" var="bar">  </g:each>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty sure you can return multiple things in that last line:

[ fooList: Foo.list( params ),
  barList: Bar.list( params ) ]

Answer (score 0):

The comma in the accepted answer is correct, you can remove the // line.